# How will you get youtube link from the following embed URL

Tags: video, flash, youtube, youtube-api

I want to watch this video on YouTube but I found this embedded in a site. Is there a way to retrieve the youtube.com URL from this embedded URL ?

```
<embed src="//www.youtube.com/get_player" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="690" height="540" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" 
flashvars="flvurl=http://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id%3Dfcfaf45aa5d77dff%26itag%3D5%26source%3Dblogger%26app%3Dblogger%26ip%3D0.0.0.0%26ipbits%3D0%26expire%3D1459608091%26sparams%3Did,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire%26signature%3D274D3FE371C996B06F9CF1F41CAD353269BFD77B.3845BB34221EFFF332FFAA610F12D2FC75CD6D5E%26key%3Dck2"
allowfullscreen="true">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the URL that's listed in `flashvars` after `flvurl=`.

```
http://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id%3Dfcfaf45aa5d77dff%26itag%3D5%26source%3Dblogger%26app%3Dblogger%26ip%3D0.0.0.0%26ipbits%3D0%26expire%3D1459608091%26sparams%3Did,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire%26signature%3D274D3FE371C996B06F9CF1F41CAD353269BFD77B.3845BB34221EFFF332FFAA610F12D2FC75CD6D5E%26key%3Dck2
```

Use a service like [UrlDecode.org](http://urldecode.org/) to decode the %xx parts of the url.

```
http://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=fcfaf45aa5d77dff&itag=5&source=blogger&app=blogger&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1459608091&sparams=id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=274D3FE371C996B06F9CF1F41CAD353269BFD77B.3845BB34221EFFF332FFAA610F12D2FC75CD6D5E&key=ck2
```

Then use a service like [Redirect Detective](http://redirectdetective.com/) to get the redirects.

```
http://r5---sn-q4f7sn7s.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=fcfaf45aa5d77dff&itag=5&source=blogger&app=blogger&ip=192.185.4.40&ipbits=0&expire=1459608091&sparams=expire,id,ip,ipbits,itag,mm,mn,ms,mv,nh,pl,source&signature=26F3DB9ADE1F7629D3516A87346AAEA3363438DF.46326FF4F9C90989B2918E881C388639A6EE1173&key=cms1&pl=18&redirect_counter=1&req_id=ee88483f2e0e38e&cms_redirect=yes&mm=30&mn=sn-q4f7sn7s&ms=nxu&mt=1457844832&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjAxLmRmdzA2KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE#sthash.82Eefku9.dpuf
```

This URL seems to be a direct link to the raw video. The `v=xxxxxxx` part of a YouTube url is likely a key for a database entry. Without access to that database, you're not going to be able to reverse a video url into a YouTube url. (Also, the embed code you provided is quite a bit different than the embed codes YouTube provides these days.)

Comment: maybe this is not even in youtube and they just used a youtube player to play this flv ?

Comment: @user570064 That could very well be. As Google owns YouTube, it could be that other Google services allow video sharing via the YouTube player but those videos aren't strictly YouTube videos.